# Split a large gz compressed file into smaller compressed file gz

Tags: unix, python3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My requirement is to load a gz file from gcs to BQ. I am using python and Airflow but it is throwing an error that if a single compressed file size is greater than 5 GB, then we can't load it. I have tried bash operator with split function, but the files which I am getting is not having the data which is present in the Actual file. Split files are having some junk data. I want the split files also in gz format.
Input file - test.gz

```
gsutil cp gs://test/test.gz - | 
split -b 1G -z - /tmp/split_file_ | 
gsutil cp /tmp/split_file_* gs://testing/
```

What I am missing? Or is there any faster/efficient way?

Comment: You copy files into a sub-directory instead of combining them. Use `cat` instead of `cp`, something like : `cat /tmp/split_file_* > gs://testing/test.gz`. (I'm guessing since I don't know your environment.)

Comment: If I will combine them, it will create single file again, but my requirement is to have multiple smaller files of 1GB file. My split files created in local environment is like split_fileaa.gz, split_fileab.gz and so on. I am copying these files to my GCS bucket testing

Answer (score 0):

You are copying all the files into a sub-directory instead of
combining them into one file.

You need to use `cat` instead of `cp`, something like:

```
cat /tmp/split_file_* > gs://testing/test.gz
```

(I'm guessing here since I don't know your environment.)

Comment: If I will combine them, it will create single file again, but my requirement is to have multiple smaller files of 1GB file. My split files created in local environment is like split_fileaa.gz, split_fileab.gz and so on. I am copying these files to my GCS bucket testing

Comment: The split command cuts chunks on byte boundaries. AFAIK no software exists to produce multiple stand-alone archives of a given size. However, for you it should be very easy to divide the documents into two or more folders and zip each separately, avoiding the 5 GB limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide step by step command to use? For ex- I have a gz file of size 12 GB in GCS and I want to load that to BQ. I am using python and Airflow. I can use bash operator, right? Can you provide steps? Let's say file name is test.gz, present in testing bucket and  wants to load in a BQ table result. I am trying since last week but splitting is not working as expected

Comment: The idea is not to work on the archive, but to zip the original files, and if required then to unzip it. You then zip the files in bunches.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to explain this? I am pretty new on this. Please share it. I have a file "text.gz" of size 12 GB. How we can split it into 4 GB chunks say- text1.gz, text2.gz,text3.gz. So that we can load it to BQ

Comment: Learn about [Using gzip and gunzip in Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/gzip-and-gunzip). You may experiment with small files while learning. Then do `gunzip` of the large archive into a temporary folder, and do `gzip` of some into several subsets of size that can be uploaded.